# Is imgur using a database to store their images?

Tags: database, imgur

I'm sure this post will be shutdown by the hive.  Just post the answer if you know it.

Just wondering if imgur.com is using a database or a filesystem to store all their images.

I did some research http://imgur.com/blog/2013/06/04/tech-tuesday-our-technology-stack/ and didn't really get an answer.

Comment: https://blog.imgur.com/2013/04/09/tech-tuesday-imgurs-database-backup-strategy/

Answer (score 2):

They use S3 (AWS) to store the image data; and MySQL to host the names/link associations.

Comment: Any source for this answer?